# Why can't I return an object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does this always return an undefined in React with Redux?

```
searchCustomer = id =>{
customers = [...this.props.data];
customers.forEach(customer=>){if(customer.id === id){return customer}};
}

customerDetails = e =>{
const customer = this.searchCustomer(id);
console.log(customer);

}
```

The console log is always undefined. If you log the object before it's returned it shows the correct object, but you never get a return value in the customerDetail function.

Comment: `forEach(customer=>)` should be a syntax error. Are you sure your code is what you're showing us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cause you can not return in `forEach`

change to

```
searchCustomer = id => this.props.data.find(customer => customer.id === id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return the value from the `forEach` loop like that... Try using `find` function instead, it's muhc easier...

```
searchCustomer = id => {
    return this.props.data.find(customer => customer.id === id)
}

customerDetails = e => {
    const customer = this.searchCustomer(id);
    console.log(customer);
}
```

Comment: Why `filter and not `find`?

Comment: find stop when the first callback condition is true, here goal is to find all customers with this id i guess. you can reduce the code by doing this : `id => [...this.props.data].filter(customer => customer.id === id);`

Comment: You can use `find` also, it will stop after having found one

Comment: Code updated with find and using directly this.props.data without copying the data

Comment: @Yanis-git: The original code has a `return customer` (singular) inside a `forEach` (which terminates the loop early); furthermore (though not explicitly a part of the question), an `id` that matches multiple objects is not really an `id`. What is the basis for your opinion that the goal here is to find all customers with this `id`?

Answer (score -1):

You aren't returning anything from `searchCustomer`. It should be

```
searchCustomer = id =>{
    customers = [...this.props.data];
    customers.forEach(customer=>){if(customer.id === id){return customer}};
    return customers;
}
```